# обойти элементы в блоке и выполнить поиск символа

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Есть блок:

```
<ul class="Nav__Level--All">
   <li class="Nav__Item--Level-3"><a class="Nav__Link--Level-3">Города:</a></li>
   <li class="Nav__Item--Level-3"><a class="Nav__Link--Level-3">Москва</a></li>
   <li class="Nav__Item--Level-3"><a class="Nav__Link--Level-3">Воронеж</a></li>
</ul>
```

Нужно в этом блоке найти элемент с символом ":" и покрасить этот элемент в красный цвет, в данном случае это Города: .

```
var obj = $('.Nav__Link--Level-3').text();
for(var item in obj){
        if(obj[item].indexOf(':') > -1){
            $(this).css("color", "red");
    }
}
```

Думал так получится, но нет..

Comment: `$(this)` -> `$(obj[item])`

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :

Comment: В комментарии показано что на что надо заменить в приведенном коде

Comment: я понял, я заменил и получил ошибку в концсоле

Comment: а, все, понял ты по строке идешь а не по элементам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо обхода по строке, которую возвращает [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) лучше идти непосредственно по элементам, например с помощью [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/), и проверять их текстовое содержимое, например с помощью свойства [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

```
el.textContent.indexOf(':') > -1
```

Либо воспользоваться селектором [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), который выбирает все элементы содержащие указанный текст.

Примеры:

```js
var obj = $('.Nav__Link--Level-3').each((_, el) => {
  if (el.textContent.indexOf(':') > -1) {
    $(el).css("color", "red");
  }
});

var obj = $('.Nav__Link--Level-4:contains(":")').css("color", "green");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="Nav__Level--All">
  <li class="Nav__Item--Level-3"><a class="Nav__Link--Level-3">Города:</a></li>
  <li class="Nav__Item--Level-3"><a class="Nav__Link--Level-3">Москва</a></li>
  <li class="Nav__Item--Level-3"><a class="Nav__Link--Level-3">Воронеж</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="Nav__Level--All">
  <li class="Nav__Item--Level-4"><a class="Nav__Link--Level-4">Города:</a></li>
  <li class="Nav__Item--Level-4"><a class="Nav__Link--Level-4">Москва</a></li>
  <li class="Nav__Item--Level-4"><a class="Nav__Link--Level-4">Воронеж</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `var obj = ` не играет роли, однако)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, да, это просто копипаст был

Comment: спасибо большое!